# How can I conditionally display a dropdown based on the value of another dropdown in thymeleaf java

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

Consider the following dropdowns

```html
<form advert="form" autocomplete="off" class="sky-form" method="post" name="form" th:action="@{/adverts/save}"
    th:object="${advert}">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Type of advert</label>
        <select class="form-control" required="required" th:field="*{advertType}">
            <option value="">----Select----</option>
            <option th:each="type : ${advertTypes}" th:text="${type.name}" th:value="${{type}}">
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group" id="station" th:if="${advertType == 'OnAir'}">
        <label>Select Radio Station</label>
        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{radioStation}">
            <option value="">----Select a Radio Station----</option>
            <option th:each="radioStation : ${radioStations}" th:text="${radioStation.name}"
                th:value="${{radioStation}}">
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

The code is failing to conditionally display the second dropdown i.e #station I also tried  using `th:if="${advert.advertType == 'OnAir'}"` as the conditional but to no avail.

Is there a bug with thymeleaf here or am i using the conditionals incorrectly here

Comment: Thymeleaf is server site rendered, you have to use JS for that.

Comment: `th:if="${advertType == 'OnAir'}"` - that logic only exists on the server (as noted by @ValerijDobler). All Thymeleaf is evaluated and replaced by HTML _on the server_. The browser only receives rendered HTML. Thymeleaf cannot respond to user clicks (if that's what you mean by "_to no avail_").

Comment: ok noted with thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resorting to hiding and showing the dropdown using jquery as a workaround

```
script th:inline="none">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // select the advertType dropdown
        const advertTypeSelect = $('select[name="advertType"]');

        // select the div with id "station"
        const stationDiv = $('#station');

        // hide the div initially
        stationDiv.hide();

        // add change event listener to the advertType dropdown
        advertTypeSelect.change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === 'ONAIR') {
                // show the div if ONAIR is selected
                stationDiv.show();
            } else {
                // hide the div otherwise
                stationDiv.hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am not a fan of this approach as it is not conservative