# Additional textbox depending on option value isn't showing correctly

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am trying to embed an extra text field if a specific option value is chosen. The text field is showing up, but it doesn't work as it should be working.

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add Zulassung</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Zulassungsfristen</a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/initabs/add}">Add Initabs</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/kartenmodule/add}">Add Modul</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/chipproduktion-frist/add}">Add Chipproduktionsfrist</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/kartenmodule}">View Kartenmodule</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>

        <form th:action="@{/kartenmodule/{id}/kartenausgabe-frist/add(id=${kartenmodul.id})}" th:object="${kartenausgabeFrist}" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" th:value="${kartenmodul.id}" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="zulassungEnde">Zulassungsende:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zulassungEnde" th:field="*{zulassungEnde}" placeholder="Enter Zulassungsende">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="beschreibung">Beschreibung:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="beschreibung" th:field="*{beschreibung}">
                <option value="">Please choose...</option>
                     <option value="V1">V1</option>
                     <option value="V2">V2</option>
                     <option value="V3">V3</option>
                     <option value="Sonstiges">Sonstiges</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group sonstige-beschreibung" th:classappend="${beschreibung == 'V1'} ? 'show' : 'hide'">
             <label for="sonstigeBeschreibung">Sonstige Beschreibung:</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sonstigeBeschreibung" th:field="*{sonstigeBeschreibung}" placeholder="Enter Beschreibung">
        </div>

        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Zulassung</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Kartenausgabe class:

```
package com.example.demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Kartenausgabe {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        
        private String zulassungEnde;
        
        private String beschreibung;
        
        private String sonstigeBeschreibung;
        
        
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "module_id")
        private Kartenmodule kartenmodule;
        
        public Kartenausgabe() {
            
        }

        public Kartenausgabe(String zulassungEnde, String beschreibung, String sonstigeBeschreibung) {
            super();
            this.zulassungEnde = zulassungEnde;
            this.sonstigeBeschreibung = sonstigeBeschreibung;
            if(sonstigeBeschreibung != null && !sonstigeBeschreibung.isEmpty()) {
                this.beschreibung = beschreibung + " - " + sonstigeBeschreibung; 
            }
            else {
                this.beschreibung = beschreibung;
            }
            
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getZulassungEnde() {
            return zulassungEnde;
        }

        public void setZulassungEnde(String zulassungEnde) {
            this.zulassungEnde = zulassungEnde;
        }

        public Kartenmodule getKartenmodule() {
            return kartenmodule;
        }

        public void setKartenmodule(Kartenmodule kartenmodule) {
            this.kartenmodule = kartenmodule;
        }

        public String getBeschreibung() {
            return beschreibung;
        }

        public void setBeschreibung(String beschreibung) {
            this.beschreibung = beschreibung;
        }

        public String getSonstigeBeschreibung() {
            return sonstigeBeschreibung;
        }

        public void setSonstigeBeschreibung(String sonstigeBeschreibung) {
            this.sonstigeBeschreibung = sonstigeBeschreibung;
        }
        
        
        
        
}
```

I am expecting that the additional textform only appears when V1 is chosen for the Beschreibung. Otherwise the additional Textform should be hidden.
I also tried to use th:if condition but this isn't working as well.

Comment: this is a client side expectation....from a server side framework :) (unless you send a "request to the server", thymeleaf has no chance to know "what you have chosen")

Comment: [yesterday's dup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76095767/592355)